# When I download an Excel file with Axsio have problem but postman downloading correctly. Why?

Tags: reactjs, axios

When I trying download an Excel (.xlsx) file with `axios` have problem and when I open this file:

[image: Excel error 1] I get an error and on pressing "Yes" get the following [image: Excel error 2]

I have tried everything and the only between difference is that the `axios` file encoding is `UTF-8` and the `postman` file encoding is `ANSI`.

It's my code:

```js
export const DownloadMonthly = (from, to) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      return getAxios()
        .get("/monthly/download", { params: {from, to}}, 
        {
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
          headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        }})
        .then((response) => { 
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'}));
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', "monthly.xlsx");
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }) 
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@Zuka Gaprindashvili i think the issue is the type that you are assigning to the file.

if you are downloading an .xlsx you will want `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` you content type is for .xls files